# How to display parameters passed to a method in Visual Studio 2022 like in intellij idea

Tags: visual-studio

in intellij and other jetbrains idea there is output of passed parameters to method for better readability, how to customize the same in vs 2022.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1qYd.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfD7y.png)

Couldn't find any information about it.